# Deploy "exploded" folder to Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, ant, tomcat6, exploded

I just installed **Eclipse for Java EE** developers, **Created a New Project** by checking out files through SVN from a repository.

I was able to successfully generate an "**exploded**" **web app folder** through an **ANT build**.

> How do I **deploy this exploded folder** (not .war file) to **Tomcat**? **Any configuration** that needs to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an ant target that copies the folder directly into the deploy folder of tomcat, usually `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`. Tomcat should then deploy the app in it's container.